# grep entire filesystem blocks on devices

Tags: shell, grep, search, pfsense

### Command

```
grep -rHinF --colour=always -e "aa:aa:aa:aa" /
```

### Output

```
grep: /dev/geom.ctl: Operation not supported by device
grep: /dev/devctl: Device busy
```

It seems that `grep` can not proceed because it is waiting for a device.
How can I skip such devices?

Comment: Does your `grep` support `--exclude-dir` option? `grep -rHinF --colour=always --exclude-dir=/dev/ -e "aa:aa:aa:aa" /`

Comment: @manatwork unfortunately no, the distribution I use is _pfSense_ and is based on _nanobsd_

Comment: GNU grep? `-D skip`

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to grep the *entire* file system? You'll likely want to skip `/proc` and probably some other trees. Actually, you likely need just a couple of top-level directories (e.g. `/etc` and similar).

Comment: @peterph I have not thought of leaving unnecessary directories out. That is a good suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `find` is available, try:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -rHinF --colour=always -e "aa:aa:aa:aa" {} +
```

This only applies to regular files so it will skip block and character devices.  See `man find`.

You probably want to skip directories like `/proc` or `/sys`; as Stephane Chazelas points out in the comments, some files in there will block (remain open, hanging the search) when you read them.  To do this, you could try the `-xdev` aka. `-mount` directive, presuming the rest of your filesystem is on one device.  If the `-fstype` directive works for you, that would be better (unfortunately it does not work for me on linux).

IMO, rather than fiddling with this, you should just repeat the process for whichever toplevel directories you really want to search, rather than trying to do it all in one go (in which case you may not need find...)

Comment: but some of directories should be excluded.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh : There's nothing about that in the OP.  However, I've added a note about it.

Comment: `/proc` does cause problems especially as `root` (think `kmsg`, `mem`, `kmem`...)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas : Thanks, I had not noticed that -- corrected.

Comment: Using the find command mentioned by @goldilocks along with the option `-xdev  Don't descend directories on other filesystems` might give you better results. I am assuming that you are after only those "real files", not the `proc` and `dev` filesystems.